Looping buffer audio recorder app for iPhone
I need an iPhone app that is essentially a “looping buffer” audio recorder, as they’re called.
Basically, the idea is a program/app that is constantly recording, in my case audio, but only stores the last X amount of time in memory (e.g. the last 10 mins.)
And then of course you can save the last few minutes if you wish.
These are usually used by gamers who don’t want to take up a ton of storage but want to be able to capture a clip if unexpected.
Like I said, I want one for audio only, that can continue to operate while the phone is asleep.
